# Hash Table Resizing, Linear Probing and Complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, hashtable

I'm working through some old exam papers and came across the following:

> Demonstrate how a closed address hashing algorithm works using the
>   data set `{4, 2, 12, 3, 9, 11, 7, 8, 13, 18}` as an input example.
>
> Assume the lenght of the array is initially 7. You should demonstrate:
>
> i. how the hash table is built, step-by-step ii. how a search on a
>   hash table can be acheived in O(1) time.

Now, given that the array is initially set to 7, the largest hash function I can use is `n mod 7`, as there are are more elements to be inserted than the size of the array, the array must be resized.

I am assuming that the hash function remains the same after resizing?

Regarding the second part, how can `O(1)` search be achieved if many elements hash to the same value? Surely, I need to sequentially through clustered elements in the array?

Is this hypothesis correct?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

after resizing your hashtable. you should do an "expensive" rehashing. That is, you have to rehashing existing keys, to allocate them new slots. Your hash function then would be `id mod newSize`.

good implementation won't do resize/rehashing when the hashtable is full. there is a load factor, performance of open addressing/linear probing approach would be dramatically getting down when load factor higher than 0.75 (or 0.8? don't remember exactly) Therefore, when load factor reaches a limit (0.75 e.g.) resizing/rehashing will be executed.

the hashfunction cost constant time, so getting element costs constant time too.

Comment: But doesnt that assume that I can get to each element directly? If I am using linear probing and have a long chain of elements with the same hash code this could equate to O(n) ?

Comment: for open addressing, to find a free slot, worst case would be going through the hashtable. not going through your element list.